# Creating a list of strings during run time. C#

Tags: c#, string, list

What I need to do I create a list of strings during one time. What the project is supposed to do is separate the input into two categories, usernames and usertypes. input will be similar to : john admin
smith teacher
Allen admin.
output will be like this:
admin john, allen.

teacher smith

this is the code that I have right now but I cannot figure out how to add the names to groups during runtime.

```
       Regex regex = new Regex(@"([A-z]{1,})\s([a-z]{1,})");
        List<string> input= new List<string>();
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        List<string> groups = new List<string>();

        int i =0;
        string experimentalString=null;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the users' names and corresponding groups seperated by a whitespace," +
            " or type sort to show results ");
        while (string.Compare(experimentalString ,"sort")!=0)
        {
            experimentalString = null; 
            experimentalString =  Console.ReadLine();
            Match match = regex.Match(experimentalString);
            if (match.Success)
            {

                input.Add(experimentalString);
                Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
            }
            else 
                throw new Exception ("invalid input format");
            //if (input[i].Equals("sort", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            //{
            //    break;
            //}
            i++;  
        }
        for (int count = 0; count < input.Count-1; i++)
        {
            names.Add(input[i].Substring(0, input[i].IndexOf(' ')));

            groups.Add(input[i].Substring(input[i].IndexOf(' '), input.Count - 1));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Groups property.

```
foreach(var match in regex.Matches(inputStr).Cast<Match>())
{
    var name = match.Groups[1];
    var type = match.Groups[2];
}
```

You also need to use a class, you should not use sperate lists.

```
public class User
{
    public User(string name, string type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Type { get; }
}
```

Then you can have list of Users.

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

//...

foreach(var match in regex.Matches(inputStr).Cast<Match>())
{
    var name = match.Groups[1];
    var type = match.Groups[2];

     users.Add(new User(name, type));
}
```

If you want to group users by their type use Linq extension method "GroupBy".

```
var groups = users.GroupBy(u => u.Type);

 foreach(var group in groups)
 {
     // group contains all users with same type
     foreach(var user in group)
     {
          //...
     }
 }
```

If you want to save groups in some sort of collection, i suggest you to use Dictionary.

```
 var dictionary = groups.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Now you can access to list of users with same type, using Type as key.

```
 var teachers = dictionary["teacher"];
 var admins = dictionary["admin"];
```

In order to print User in console you should print properties one by one like this.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.Name}, Type:{user.Type}");
```

Alternatively you can override ToString in User class.

```
// Put this method in User class
public override string ToString()
{
   return $"User Name: {Name}, User Type {Type}";
}
```

Now you can print User easily

```
  Console.WriteLine(user);
```

Comment: Then how do we sort users into groups without printing duplicate group names?

Comment: Im not sure what you are referring to as "duplicate group names". Can you elaborate more?

Comment: so if more than one user have the type admin, it should be printed to the console as admin john, smith. not admin john admin smith

Comment: Thank you, but I still have one more problem. Whenever I try to do Console.write(user), I get this printed out :System.Linq.Grouping`2[System.String,ConsoleApp1.Users]This is the code I am using   var groups = users.GroupBy(u => u.Type);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Console.Write(group);
                // group contains all users with same type
                foreach (var user in group)
                {
                    Console.Write(user+",");
                }
            }

Comment: Because thats default behavior of classes and how they are converted to string. You can change this behavior by overriding method. See update

Comment: its is printing nothing at all

Comment: Please update your question with new code so i can see where problem is.

Comment: In fact nevermind it is working. I APPRECIATE YOU SIR!! you are a life saver.

Comment: Im glad it helped, you can accept this answer if it answered your question ;)